# How to parse xml file that is encoded with another encoder different from utf-8 with using NSXMLParser in objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, encoding, nsxmlparser

Is there a way to parse xml file that is encoded with windows-1254 with using NSXMLParser? When i try, didStartElement method not called.

Code is

```
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:webData]; 
XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser: objectList];
[parser setReqType:reqType]; 
[xmlParser setDelegate:parser]; 
[xmlParser parse];
```

XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1254" ?> 
 <CANLIMACLAR> 
 <CANLIMACLARROWS> 
<TARIH>19/10/2009 21:15</TARIH> 
<TAKIM1>Union Berlin</TAKIM1> 
<TAKIM2>Fürth</TAKIM2> 
<SONUC1>1</SONUC1> 
<SONUC2>2</SONUC2> 
<DK_DURUM>Maç Sonu</DK_DURUM> ... 
</CANLIMACLARROWS> ...
 </CANLIMACLAR>
```

Comment: Can you post your code? And perhaps the prolog of the XML file itself?

Comment: NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:webData];
XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser: objectList];
[parser setReqType:reqType];
[xmlParser setDelegate:parser];
[xmlParser parse];

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1254" ?> 
- <CANLIMACLAR>
- <CANLIMACLARROWS>
  <TARIH>19/10/2009 21:15</TARIH> 
  <TAKIM1>Union Berlin</TAKIM1> 
  <TAKIM2>Fürth</TAKIM2> 
  <SONUC1>1</SONUC1> 
  <SONUC2>2</SONUC2> 
  <DK_DURUM>Maç Sonu</DK_DURUM>  
  ... 
  </CANLIMACLARROWS>
...
</CANLIMACLAR>

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget if parse() returns NO you can check parseError to see what happened:

```
if ([parser parse] == NO)
{
   NSError *error = [parser parserError];
   NSString *readableMessage = [error localizedDescription];
   NSLog(@"Error occurred: %@\n", readableMessage);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, i implemented it, but i think there is a missing character at "[parser parseError]", it must be "[parser parserError]".

Answer (score -1):

I removed the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1254" ?>` part from xml data and then i send it to xmlParser, so there is no problem anymore.

Comment: However this is not a fix - the problem is hat the data is not XML and the supplier needs to fix it